# Heroku python how to use pip

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I made a simple Nodejs api which calls python. I tested a lot on my local machineand it works but when I deployed it to heroku with requirements.txt.
the folder structure

```
-NodeAPI
 --app.js
 --requirements.txt //I added again for a try
 --pythonscrpt
   ---home.py
   ---requirements.txt
```

When I run this command on my local  `heroku logs --tail` ,It says

```
2020-08-10T09:08:06.538799+00:00 app[web.1]: import pandas as pd
2020-08-10T09:08:06.538799+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Npm packages installed automaticly well but how can I install this packages.
Forums says `pip install -r requirements.txt`  but when I run it it work on my local machine not on heroku.
Is anybody deployed python app to heroku

the requirements.txt

```
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib==3.3.0
numpy==1.19.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
openpyxl==3.0.4
pandas==1.1.0
pdfrw==0.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
regex==2020.7.14
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rfc3986==1.4.0
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.5.2
seaborn==0.10.1
six==1.15.0
sklearn==0.0
sniffio==1.1.0
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tqdm==4.48.2
urllib3==1.25.10
```

What I a supposed to do install all this packages ot heroku
I added Python builpack from website settings but now Nodejs does not working neither
heroku logs --tail says

```
2020-08-10T13:07:23.811477+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=sample.herokuapp.com request_id=5c559601-9076-4160-9603-9f3762f65ef9   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Did you use a virtual environment? If so did you make sure to pip install pandas in your environment?

Comment: No I am not using virtual enviorement.I can run my python script in CMD console

Comment: Is `pandas` present in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Yes it is written

Comment: Is there any missing step.Am still waiting

Comment: Did you add a Procfile ?